# Can't add a user to sharepoint...cross domain?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, cross-domain

The user can view the site, they simply always receive "ERROR: Access Denied".  The error message also picks up their domain\user as expected.

I am using SharePoint 2010.

The SharePoint server is in another domain than the user however there is a trust relationship between the two.  My user, is also in the same domain as the other and I can access the site as expected...what the hell!

I have checked, the user is a member of two SharePoint groups within the site however they have no other permissions.  I have tried it on a few users and they all have the same problem.

I believe the problem is something to do with SharePoint not being able to accept users from the domain, I just don't know where to start looking anymore?

edit -I now see a sharepoint stack exchange..sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately my problem was probably site specific.  The users I were trying to add were from a second domain.  This domain does have a trust to my primary domain and as such I should have been able to add groups directly to my sharepoint instance.  Unfortunately I couldn't.

My work around was simply to create a SharePoint group and add the users (from the second domain I must add) directly.  This works fine.

I actually don't know the reason why the AD groups didn't work but the individual users did...if anyone has any insight let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

you will need to make sure the user groups have the proper "read" permissions within share point.

in share point: site actions --> site settings --> advanced permissions

Comment: I've already done that - I've removed the users and re-added.  I've also used "Check permissions" to confirm and the permissions are fine.  I've also check the Central Config/Web App permissions to make sure there is no problem with inheritance etc.  Adding a completely new user from within the same domain also receives the error message.

Comment: I am certain it is not a domain-trust issue.  I can add the users (and they are confirmed by sharepoint).  It must be a setting /permission somewhere in the site :(

Answer (score -1):

1. stsadm -o setapppassword -password Start123
2. stsadm -o setproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -url http://test.global.com:39449/   -pv "domain:ztb.icb.com",username without domain name,password